# BigQuery 'MERGE: command not found' command is not working

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to run a script file which contains creation of temp table, load the data, creation of test table, merge the data and delete the table in BigQuery. Intial 3 commands is working fine but MERGE command is not working.

```
bq mk --table --expiration 3600 --description "This is my source table" dataset_name.table_name 
emp_id:INTEGER,emp_name:STRING
bq load --source_format=CSV income_tracking.temp_table /home/username/physical.csv
bq mk --table --expiration 3600 --description "This is my target table" dataset_name.table_name 
emp_id:INTEGER,emp_name:STRING
MERGE dataset.test_data T
USING dataset.temp_table S
ON T.emp_id = S.emp_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET emp_name = S.emp_name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (emp_id, emp_name) VALUES(emp_id, emp_name)
bq rm -f -t project_id:dataset_name.temp_table
```

Here MERGE command is not working and error is -

```
username@cloudshell:~ (bmg-dt-prd-svc)$ bash bq_merge.sh
Table 'project_id:dataset_name.table_name' successfully created.
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r75d2358a0232abdb_0000016f227e7a0f_1 ... (1s) Current status: DONE   
Table 'project_id:dataset_name.table_name' successfully created.
bq_merge.sh: line 4: MERGE: command not found
bq_merge.sh: line 5: USING: command not found
bq_merge.sh: line 6: ON: command not found
bq_merge.sh: line 7: WHEN: command not found
bq_merge.sh: line 8: UPDATE: command not found
bq_merge.sh: line 9: WHEN: command not found
bq_merge.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `emp_id,'
'q_merge.sh: line 10: `  INSERT (emp_id, emp_name) VALUES(emp_id, emp_name)
```

What would be the solution, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to run the query as a bash command.
You should replace the query in your bash script with the following command:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
"""
MERGE dataset.test_data T
USING dataset.temp_table S
ON T.emp_id = S.emp_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET emp_name = S.emp_name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (emp_id, emp_name) VALUES(emp_id, emp_name)
"""
```